# Patching .htaccess file

Tags: 7, composer, version-control

I need to patch `.htaccess` file which is located in project's root (`docroot` in this case), my project is written using composer and I created a patch using git, added it to the /patches directory and wrote a composer.json entry:

```
"drupal/drupal": [
          {
            "title": "htaccess patch",
            "url": "docroot/profiles/laeg/patches/redirects.patch"
          }
        ]
```

Sadly after running `composer update` my patch doesn't appear in the patches list therefore it is not applied. I was told that I should patch `drupal/drupal` but it seems to not be a case, has some done anything like this and could suggest me something? Project is running Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4):

For drupal 8, use the following.
In the 'scripts' section of your composer.json, add

```
"post-drupal-scaffold-cmd": [
  "patch -p0 < patches/htaccess.patch"
]
```

Comment: I had to use -p1 instead of -p0 for it to work for me.

Comment: -p1 for me too! Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

A little late, but check out https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-scaffold/issues/45. They give a few solutions for handling the issue.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.